# Stop running worker thread by button click event

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Need to Abort or terminate a thread by **clicking a button**.. I tried a lot of things to stop it. Here is button click events for that...
After clicking Button 1 , following thread will be started.

Here is **Button1 click event**

```
            Thread threadshippingandnewuserbonus = new Thread(() =>
            {
                GetShipping = ShipingCostAndNewUserBonus();
                Action action = new Action(ShowShipping);
                this.BeginInvoke(action);
            }
        );threadshippingandnewuserbonus.Start();
```

Now I want to stop or abort this using Button 2 event. So i wrote following code to abort the thread running

**Here is Button2 click event**

```
            Thread threadshippingandnewuserbonus = new Thread(() =>
            {
                GetShipping = ShipingCostAndNewUserBonus();
                Action action = new Action(ShowShipping);
                this.BeginInvoke(action);
            }
        ); threadshippingandnewuserbonus.Abort();
```

But. Thread doesn't stop.. it is still running, what should I do?

Comment: Are you targeting the .NET Framework or the .NET 6?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias my target frame work *.Net Framework 4.7.2* ,

Comment: How do you know that the `Thread` doesn't stop when you invoke the `Abort` method? Do you query the [`IsAlive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isalive) property and it returns `true`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thread doesn't stop. I check it another way using a messagebox... after clicking abort() on button 2. it is still running and show the output via messagebox... how do  i use that ```isAlive``` property. ?

Comment: After calling `threadlongname.Abort();` you can wait for half a second `Thread.Sleep(500)`, and then show a message box that displays the value of the `threadlongname.IsAlive` property.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias your method may work. if these threads are in same button.. I am creating same thread in 2 button.it means different places. compiler think these thread are as different threads even though it has same code so **button two thread** cannot abort **button one thread** ...

Comment: Oh, I see. So both buttons have exactly the same code in their `Click` event handler?

Comment: yes.. But i think they are not same

Comment: can you give me a method to abort this thread?

Comment: Consider converting this code to use Tasks and `async` `await`, and use a `CancellationToken` to abort.

Comment: @herryjack - If the code in your question is literally the code you are running then you are creating two threads and only aborting the second one. Can you please clarify exactly what your code is?

Comment: i fixed this problem.. I declared a thread out side of scope, and starting and aborting will be happened in the button click event

Comment: @herryjack - Sorry, is that a clarification of your code or a fix you've made? Can you clarify please?